# simple but (seemingly?) tricky recurrence

Tags: recurrence-relations, asymptotics, functional-equations

I came across the following very simple recurrence-style expression but am having trouble solving it:
$$T(2n) \in \theta(T(n) \log(T(n)))$$
for sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

My first thought was to take the logarithm of both sides and apply the Master Theorem but the "$f(n)$" term unfortunately is not in the right form. Repeated expanding quickly yields a mess. Wolfram Alpha was no use.

Plugging in $T(n) = n^a$ makes the left side grow too slowly so $T$ must grow faster than any polynomial. But plugging in $T(n) = \exp(\log(n)^b)$, $b>1$, causes the left side to grow too fast so $T$ must grow more slowly. So it seems $T$ is super-polynomial but *barely*.

What approaches are viable for such an equation?

Edit: cross-posted [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/85881/simple-but-seemingly-tricky-recurrence).

Comment: Then why wouldn't you plug something barely super-polynomial, like $\exp(\log n\cdot\log\log n)$?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I have tried that function, and in the cross post, you can see that someone answered the question with that function. However, it isn't quite right.

Comment: Yes, I know, but at least this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm closing this question because further answers should better be posted on [cs.se] now that it has a first answer there.